# OroCRM Version upgrade from 4.0.0 to 4.1 Possible Errors

Tags: nginx, upgrade, centos7, php-7, orocrm

May i know what are all the issues occurred OroCRM Version upgrade from 4.0.0 to 4.1.

Server Information : Centos7, Ngins, PHP 7

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the customization you have. The plain application can be upgraded with a few commands, and no issues, see 
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/upgrade-to-new-version/

If you have any code customizations, please follow the official upgrade guide. You can start from https://github.com/oroinc/crm-application/blob/master/UPGRADE.md